# Device Model from React Native Device Info for iPhone X

Tags: react-native

general question here. I'm using [rn-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-device-info) library. I want to know what will be the return on `console.log("Device Model", DeviceInfo.getModel());` for iPhone X? Is it "iPhone X" or "iPhone 10"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return `iPhone X`.

Source: [RNDeviceInfo.m](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/blob/master/ios/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceInfo.m)

PS: Make sure you are on the latest version of rn-device-info

Answer (score 2):

This is might be old question to answer but here is answer for people who looking for it, without installing any external libraries create file name **isIphoneX.js**

insert this code

```
import { Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';

export function isIphoneX() {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('window');

  return (
    // This has to be iOS
    Platform.OS === 'ios' &&

    // Check either, iPhone X or XR
    (isIPhoneXSize(dim) || isIPhoneXrSize(dim))
  );
}

export function isIPhoneXSize(dim) {
  return dim.height == 812 || dim.width == 812;
}

export function isIPhoneXrSize(dim) {
  return dim.height == 896 || dim.width == 896;
}
```

the code above will check if it's iphone X, Xr 
you can update the code as you wish just create new functions and export them and use it inside you code.

Answer (score 1):

Add NativeModules from 'react-native; library

then you can check if the device is iPhonex by 
NativeModules.DeviceInfo.isIPhoneX_deprecated 
if true, the device is iphoneX and vice versa.

This is deprecated but still works in RN 55.4. It may not be the solution for the future releases.

Comment: is that method deprecated? sounds like it's deprecated

Comment: a method can be deprecated and still work... it's labeled "deprecated" in the method name, so I'm pretty sure it's deprecated. It may still work in 55.4 but it's deprecated, which means it's being phased out and won't work in future releases

Comment: @Cole yes you are right, it is deprecated but it still work until RN 55.4. It may not be the solution for the future releases.